# Installing the Deprecated Nexus 7 Gouper

Tags: nexus-7

I am looking to install an older image for the Nexus 7 2012 since its deprecated, I was wondering how to go about installing the older unsupported version.

I have followed the guide here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

I have just reached "Install Ubuntu on device" where I run `ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap` but obviously I have the 2012 one so It comes back with the `Channel grouper not found on server` error.

Where do I find the older image?

How do I flash an image I've downloaded?

Comment: You cannot install "devel" channel, only "stable" on grouper. You may also need to specify "--device grouper" as an option as well.

Comment: You'll find it more effective to ask one question at a time here. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install to the older version you need to use the 'stable' channel vs the 'devel' channel. From the bootloader run this

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=stable --device grouper --bootstrap
```

This should download and install 'Version-10' to the device